# How to convert half byte character to full byte character japanese

Tags: javascript, typescript, unicode, cjk

I have to try to convert each input on text box that converts to a full byte character please find below my code...

```
 static convertToFullWidth(string: any) {
    if(string){
      var listOfCharacters = '';
      for (let index = 0; index < string.length; index++) {
        var selectedElement = string[index].charCodeAt(0);
        if (0x0020 < selectedElement && selectedElement < 0x007F) {
          selectedElement = 0xFF00 + (selectedElement - 0x0020);
        }
        if (0x0020 === selectedElement) {
          selectedElement = 0x3000;
        }
        listOfCharacters += String.fromCharCode(selectedElement);
      }
      return listOfCharacters;
    }
  }
```

Attempts:

Working input -
**ウマングナイ**
Not Working
**ｳﾏﾝｸﾅｲ**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a mathematical pattern to the unicode codepoints that you could use here. It seems there isn't consistency between one and the other.

[This page](https://www.yoheim.net/blog.php?q=20191101) provides a simple approach, which is just to have a mapping from half-width to full-width and use a regex replace on the matched characters:

```js
function hankana2Zenkana(str) {
    var kanaMap = {
        'ｶﾞ': 'ガ', 'ｷﾞ': 'ギ', 'ｸﾞ': 'グ', 'ｹﾞ': 'ゲ', 'ｺﾞ': 'ゴ',
        'ｻﾞ': 'ザ', 'ｼﾞ': 'ジ', 'ｽﾞ': 'ズ', 'ｾﾞ': 'ゼ', 'ｿﾞ': 'ゾ',
        'ﾀﾞ': 'ダ', 'ﾁﾞ': 'ヂ', 'ﾂﾞ': 'ヅ', 'ﾃﾞ': 'デ', 'ﾄﾞ': 'ド',
        'ﾊﾞ': 'バ', 'ﾋﾞ': 'ビ', 'ﾌﾞ': 'ブ', 'ﾍﾞ': 'ベ', 'ﾎﾞ': 'ボ',
        'ﾊﾟ': 'パ', 'ﾋﾟ': 'ピ', 'ﾌﾟ': 'プ', 'ﾍﾟ': 'ペ', 'ﾎﾟ': 'ポ',
        'ｳﾞ': 'ヴ', 'ﾜﾞ': 'ヷ', 'ｦﾞ': 'ヺ',
        'ｱ': 'ア', 'ｲ': 'イ', 'ｳ': 'ウ', 'ｴ': 'エ', 'ｵ': 'オ',
        'ｶ': 'カ', 'ｷ': 'キ', 'ｸ': 'ク', 'ｹ': 'ケ', 'ｺ': 'コ',
        'ｻ': 'サ', 'ｼ': 'シ', 'ｽ': 'ス', 'ｾ': 'セ', 'ｿ': 'ソ',
        'ﾀ': 'タ', 'ﾁ': 'チ', 'ﾂ': 'ツ', 'ﾃ': 'テ', 'ﾄ': 'ト',
        'ﾅ': 'ナ', 'ﾆ': 'ニ', 'ﾇ': 'ヌ', 'ﾈ': 'ネ', 'ﾉ': 'ノ',
        'ﾊ': 'ハ', 'ﾋ': 'ヒ', 'ﾌ': 'フ', 'ﾍ': 'ヘ', 'ﾎ': 'ホ',
        'ﾏ': 'マ', 'ﾐ': 'ミ', 'ﾑ': 'ム', 'ﾒ': 'メ', 'ﾓ': 'モ',
        'ﾔ': 'ヤ', 'ﾕ': 'ユ', 'ﾖ': 'ヨ',
        'ﾗ': 'ラ', 'ﾘ': 'リ', 'ﾙ': 'ル', 'ﾚ': 'レ', 'ﾛ': 'ロ',
        'ﾜ': 'ワ', 'ｦ': 'ヲ', 'ﾝ': 'ン',
        'ｧ': 'ァ', 'ｨ': 'ィ', 'ｩ': 'ゥ', 'ｪ': 'ェ', 'ｫ': 'ォ',
        'ｯ': 'ッ', 'ｬ': 'ャ', 'ｭ': 'ュ', 'ｮ': 'ョ',
        '｡': '。', '､': '、', 'ｰ': 'ー', '｢': '「', '｣': '」', '･': '・'
    };

    var reg = new RegExp('(' + Object.keys(kanaMap).join('|') + ')', 'g');
    return str
            .replace(reg, function (match) {
                return kanaMap[match];
            })
            .replace(/ﾞ/g, '゛')
            .replace(/ﾟ/g, '゜');
};

console.log(hankana2Zenkana('ｱｼﾀﾊｲｲﾃﾝｷｶﾅ､ﾌﾞｰｳﾞｰ'));
```

It also provides a function for English letters and Hindu-Arabic numerals:

```js
function hankaku2Zenkaku(str) {
  return str.replace(/[A-Za-z0-9]/g, function(s) {
    return String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0) + 0xFEE0);
  });
}

console.log(hankaku2Zenkaku('123abC')); // '１２３ａｂＣ'
```

You can chain these together to get your desired result:

```js
function hankana2Zenkana(str) {
  var kanaMap = {
    'ｶﾞ': 'ガ',
    'ｷﾞ': 'ギ',
    'ｸﾞ': 'グ',
    'ｹﾞ': 'ゲ',
    'ｺﾞ': 'ゴ',
    'ｻﾞ': 'ザ',
    'ｼﾞ': 'ジ',
    'ｽﾞ': 'ズ',
    'ｾﾞ': 'ゼ',
    'ｿﾞ': 'ゾ',
    'ﾀﾞ': 'ダ',
    'ﾁﾞ': 'ヂ',
    'ﾂﾞ': 'ヅ',
    'ﾃﾞ': 'デ',
    'ﾄﾞ': 'ド',
    'ﾊﾞ': 'バ',
    'ﾋﾞ': 'ビ',
    'ﾌﾞ': 'ブ',
    'ﾍﾞ': 'ベ',
    'ﾎﾞ': 'ボ',
    'ﾊﾟ': 'パ',
    'ﾋﾟ': 'ピ',
    'ﾌﾟ': 'プ',
    'ﾍﾟ': 'ペ',
    'ﾎﾟ': 'ポ',
    'ｳﾞ': 'ヴ',
    'ﾜﾞ': 'ヷ',
    'ｦﾞ': 'ヺ',
    'ｱ': 'ア',
    'ｲ': 'イ',
    'ｳ': 'ウ',
    'ｴ': 'エ',
    'ｵ': 'オ',
    'ｶ': 'カ',
    'ｷ': 'キ',
    'ｸ': 'ク',
    'ｹ': 'ケ',
    'ｺ': 'コ',
    'ｻ': 'サ',
    'ｼ': 'シ',
    'ｽ': 'ス',
    'ｾ': 'セ',
    'ｿ': 'ソ',
    'ﾀ': 'タ',
    'ﾁ': 'チ',
    'ﾂ': 'ツ',
    'ﾃ': 'テ',
    'ﾄ': 'ト',
    'ﾅ': 'ナ',
    'ﾆ': 'ニ',
    'ﾇ': 'ヌ',
    'ﾈ': 'ネ',
    'ﾉ': 'ノ',
    'ﾊ': 'ハ',
    'ﾋ': 'ヒ',
    'ﾌ': 'フ',
    'ﾍ': 'ヘ',
    'ﾎ': 'ホ',
    'ﾏ': 'マ',
    'ﾐ': 'ミ',
    'ﾑ': 'ム',
    'ﾒ': 'メ',
    'ﾓ': 'モ',
    'ﾔ': 'ヤ',
    'ﾕ': 'ユ',
    'ﾖ': 'ヨ',
    'ﾗ': 'ラ',
    'ﾘ': 'リ',
    'ﾙ': 'ル',
    'ﾚ': 'レ',
    'ﾛ': 'ロ',
    'ﾜ': 'ワ',
    'ｦ': 'ヲ',
    'ﾝ': 'ン',
    'ｧ': 'ァ',
    'ｨ': 'ィ',
    'ｩ': 'ゥ',
    'ｪ': 'ェ',
    'ｫ': 'ォ',
    'ｯ': 'ッ',
    'ｬ': 'ャ',
    'ｭ': 'ュ',
    'ｮ': 'ョ',
    '｡': '。',
    '､': '、',
    'ｰ': 'ー',
    '｢': '「',
    '｣': '」',
    '･': '・'
  };

  var reg = new RegExp('(' + Object.keys(kanaMap).join('|') + ')', 'g');
  return str
    .replace(reg, function(match) {
      return kanaMap[match];
    })
    .replace(/ﾞ/g, '゛')
    .replace(/ﾟ/g, '゜');
};

function hankaku2Zenkaku(str) {
  return str.replace(/[A-Za-z0-9]/g, function(s) {
    return String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0) + 0xFEE0);
  });
}

function allhankaku2Zenkaku(str) {
  return hankaku2Zenkaku(hankana2Zenkana(str));
}

console.log(allhankaku2Zenkaku('abcde01234ｱｲｳｴｵｶﾞｷﾞｸﾞｹﾞｺﾞ'));
```

Answer (score 5):

To convert halfwidth katakana to fullwidth katakana, you can simply use the string method [normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) with parameter `'NFKC'` (Normalization Form KC):

```js
let str = 'ｱｼﾀﾊｲｲﾃﾝｷｶﾅ､ﾌﾞｰｳﾞｰ';
console.log (str.normalize ('NFKC')); // -> 'アシタハイイテンキカナ、ブーヴー'
```